# Function continue running even with internet connection IONIC2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm currently sending some posts to the server through and API which works out correctly. But there are times i intentionally turn off the internet to see if my pop will work but it fails.

```
register(){
    this.loc_address=localStorage.getItem('user_location');
    this.farmer_photo=localStorage.getItem('farmer_photo');
          let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
            content: 'Please Wait'
            });
            loader.present().then(()=>{

          this.http.post("http://loclahost/app/farmer.php", { 
            'farmer_passcode':this.farmer_passcode,
            'farmer_photo':this.farmer_photo}).map(res => res.json()) .subscribe(data => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(data[0].ID));
              this.get_farmer_id=data[0].ID;

          this.http.post("http://localhost/app/add.php", { 
            'farm_name': this.farm_name, 
            'farm_address':this.loc_address}).map(res => res.json()) .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          loader.dismiss();
          let toast = this.toastcontroller.create({
            message:'Farmer registration was successful',
            duration:3000,
            position:'bottom'
          });
          toast.present();

        }),error=>{
          loader.dismiss();
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Error!',
            subTitle: 'Please check your Internet Connectivity',
            buttons: ['Try Again']
          });
          alert.present();
        }
      })


        })
  }
```

Comment: Does it shows your error alert?

Comment: no it doesn't show up the alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with your code is that the error callback is not beeing fired in the right place. Doesn't it throws an error with that code? Because your error callback is totally off your post method.

Second there are 2 error callbacks to be fired, since there's 2 http posts, so if you turn off your internet before calling the register function it'll not have the expected behaviour.

Third and last, there's no `pop` method beeing called in your code, is it the `navCtrl.pop()` you want? if so you need to use it inside your error. I'll not update the code using the navController pop method since i don't know if that's what you want.

Try this:

```
register(){
    this.loc_address=localStorage.getItem('user_location');
    this.farmer_photo=localStorage.getItem('farmer_photo');
    let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
        content: 'Please Wait'
    });
    loader.present().then(()=>{

        this.http.post("http://loclahost/app/farmer.php", { 
            'farmer_passcode':this.farmer_passcode,
            'farmer_photo':this.farmer_photo}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data[0].ID));
                this.get_farmer_id=data[0].ID;

                this.http.post("http://localhost/app/add.php", { 
                    'farm_name': this.farm_name, 
                    'farm_address':this.loc_address}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        loader.dismiss();
                        let toast = this.toastcontroller.create({
                            message:'Farmer registration was successful',
                            duration:3000,
                            position:'bottom'
                        });
                        toast.present();

                    },error=>{ // <= HERE, the error callback must be inside the executed method
                        loader.dismiss();
                        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                            title: 'Error!',
                            subTitle: 'Please check your Internet Connectivity',
                            buttons: ['Try Again']
                        });
                        alert.present();
                    })
            }, err =>{ // <= HERE, there must be 2 error callbacks
                loader.dismiss();
                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Error!',
                    subTitle: 'Please check your Internet Connectivity',
                    buttons: ['Try Again']
                });
                alert.present();
            });
    })
}
```

Hope this helps